# Why .fit() needs 2D array as the first parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('homeprices.csv')

plt.xlabel('area')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.scatter(df.area,df.price,color='red',marker='.')


reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df.area,df.price)
```

**Error Message:**

**ValueError**: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[2600 3000 3200 3600 4000].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

It works fine if I write it as :

```
reg.fit(df[['area']],df.price)
```

I would like to know the reason behind it because The second argument is passed as df.price.

My csv file:

- area,price
- 2600,550000
- 3000,565000
- 3200,610000
- 3600,680000
- 4000,725000

Comment: Please notice that requests for external resources such as in your last para are explicitly off-topic here (edited out, since this would make your question eligible for closure as off-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), variable x should be declared as

> X{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)

When you declare:

- `x = df.area` or `x = df['area']` the `x` will become `Series` type with the size `(n,)`. The size should be `(n, z)`, where `z` can be any positive integer.
- `x = df[['area']]` the `x` will become `DataFrame` type with the size `(5, 1)` which makes an `x` an acceptable input.
- `y = df.price` the `y` will become `Series` type with the size `(5,)` which s acceptable input.

> y:  array-like of shape (n_samples,)

But if I were you I declare `x` and `y` as:

```py
x = [[i] for i in df['area']]
y = [i for i in df['price']]
```

which makes both `x` and `y` as the `list` structure and set the size to the `(5, 1)`, so in the future if you want to run in any ML library (tensorflow, pytorch, keras, ...) you won't have any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the input shape, the error was raised because its shape was (N,) while the correct one should be (N,1). That's why the error message suggests you to reshape.